# Group query to get specific order

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, sharepoint-2013

I use this query to populate my gallery:

```
  function GalleryCatPopulate(url, listname, target) {

    var eng = false;
    if ((window.location.href.indexOf("lang=en") > 0)) {
        eng = true;
    }


    // Getting our list items
    $.ajax({
        url: url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/items?$select=Title,English",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            completeGalleryCat(data, target, eng);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failureGalleryCat(data, target);
        }
    });
}

function completeGalleryCat(data, target, eng) {
    var items = data.d.results;
    var prefix = "";
    var sufix = "<div class='clear'></div>";
    //if (eng)
     //  prefix = "<div class='filter selected' data-category='cat-all'>All</div>";
    //else
      //  prefix = "<div class='filter selected' data-category='cat-all'>Todas</div>";

    var menu = "";
    var cat = "";
    var title = "Transporte de Materiales";
    console.log(title.replace(/\s/g, "_").replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, ''));
    for (var item in items) {
        if (eng)
           cat = items[item].English; 
        else 
            cat = items[item].Title;

                  menu += "<div class='filter' data-category='" + cat.replace(/\s/g, "_").replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '') +"'>"+ cat +"</div>";

            }
    $(target).html(prefix + menu + sufix);

}

function failureGalleryCat(data, target) {
    $(target).text("Ocurrió un error en la carga las categorias. Por favor revise la consola para más información");
}

function GalleryContentPopulate(url, listname, target) {

    var eng = false;
    var queryGallery = "$select=Title,Description,Enlace,EncodedAbsUrl,Categoria/Title&$expand=Categoria/Title$SortField=Title&SortDir=Desc";

    if ((window.location.href.indexOf("lang=en") > 0)) {
        queryGallery = "$select=TitleEnglish,DescriptionEnglish,Enlace,EncodedAbsUrl,Categoria/English&$expand=Categoria/English";
        eng = true;
    }


   // Getting our list items
$.ajax({
url: url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/items?$top=1000&" + queryGallery, 
//url: url + "/_api/web/lists/getbycategory('Office'),

method: "GET",
headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
success: function (data) {
    completeGalleryContent(data, target, eng);
},
error: function (data) {
    failureGalleryContent(data, target);
}
});
}
function completeGalleryContent(data, target, eng) {
    var items = data.d.results;
    //console.log(items);
    var menu = "";
    var cat = "";
    for (var item in items) {
    if(items[item].DescriptionEnglish==null)
        items[item].DescriptionEnglish="";
    if(items[item].Description==null)
        items[item].Description="";
        if(items[item].Categoria.results!= null && items[item].Categoria.results!= undefined && items[item].Categoria.results.length > 0){
            cat =setCategories(eng,items[item].Categoria.results);
        }
        if (eng){
            //menu += "<div class='mega-entry " + cat + " cat-all' id='mega-entry-1' data-src='" + items[item].EncodedAbsUrl + "' data-width='' data-height='' data-lowsize=''><div class='mega-covercaption mega-square-bottom mega-landscape-right mega-portrait-bottom mega-red'><div class='mega-title'>" + items[item].TitleEnglish + "</div><p>" + items[item].DescriptionEnglish + "</p></div><div class='mega-coverbuttons'><div class='mega-link mega-red'></div><a class=' ' rel='group' href='" + items[item].EncodedAbsUrl + "' title='" + items[item].TitleEnglish + "'><div class='mega-view mega-red'></div></a></div></div>";

            menu += "<div class='mega-entry " + cat + " cat-all' id='mega-entry-1' data-src='" + items[item].EncodedAbsUrl + "' data-width='' data-height='' data-lowsize=''><div class='mega-covercaption mega-square-bottom mega-landscape-right mega-portrait-bottom mega-red'><div class='mega-title'>" + items[item].TitleEnglish + "</div><p>" + items[item].DescriptionEnglish + "</p></div><div class='mega-coverbuttons'><a class=' ' rel='group' href='" + items[item].EncodedAbsUrl + "' title='" + items[item].TitleEnglish + "'><div class='mega-view mega-red'></div></a></div></div>";
        }else{
         //menu += "<div class='mega-entry "+ cat + " cat-all' id='mega-entry-1' data-src='" + items[item].EncodedAbsUrl + "' data-width='' data-height='' data-lowsize=''><div class='mega-covercaption mega-square-bottom mega-landscape-right mega-portrait-bottom mega-red'><div class='mega-title'>" + items[item].Title + "</div><p>" + items[item].Description + "</p></div><div class='mega-coverbuttons'><div class='mega-link mega-red'></div><a class='fancybox' rel='group' href='" + items[item].EncodedAbsUrl + "' title='"+ items[item].Title +"'><div class='mega-view mega-red'></div></a></div></div>";

          menu += "<div class='mega-entry "+ cat + " cat-all' id='mega-entry-1' data-src='" + items[item].EncodedAbsUrl + "' data-width='' data-height='' data-lowsize=''><div class='mega-covercaption mega-square-bottom mega-landscape-right mega-portrait-bottom mega-red'><div class='mega-title'>" + items[item].Title + "</div><p>" + items[item].Description + "</p></div><div class='mega-coverbuttons'><a class='fancybox' rel='group' href='" + items[item].EncodedAbsUrl + "' title='"+ items[item].Title +"'><div class='mega-view mega-red'></div></a></div></div>";
        }
    } 
    $(target).html(menu);
      var api = $(target).megafoliopro(
                   {
                       filterChangeAnimation: "pagebottom",         // fade, rotate, scale, rotatescale, pagetop, pagebottom,pagemiddle
                       filterChangeSpeed: 400,                  // Speed of Transition
                       filterChangeRotate: 99,                  // If you ue scalerotate or rotate you can set the rotation (99 = random !!)
                       filterChangeScale: 0.6,                  // Scale Animation Endparameter
                       delay: 20,
                       defaultWidth: 980,
                       paddingHorizontal: 10,
                       paddingVertical: 10,
                       layoutarray: [9, 11, 5, 3, 7, 12, 4, 6, 13]      // Defines the Layout Types which can be used in the Gallery. 2-9 or "random". You can define more than one, like {5,2,6,4} where the first items will be orderd in layout 5, the next comming items in layout 2, the next comming items in layout 6 etc... You can use also simple {9} then all item ordered in Layout 9 type.
                   });

            //console.log("entra");
            // FANCY BOX ( LIVE BOX) WITH MEDIA SUPPORT


            //console.log("sale");

            // THE FILTER FUNCTION
            $('.filter').click(function () {
                $('.filter').each(function () { jQuery(this).removeClass("selected") });
                api.megafilter(jQuery(this).data('category'));
                $(this).addClass("selected");
            });
   var categorySelected = getParameterByName("Category");
  //  $('[data-category="Office"],[data-category="Oficinas"]').click();

  // Aquí agarramos la primera categoria
     $(".filter").eq(0).trigger("click");
    $("div[data-category='"+categorySelected +"']").click();
     jQuery(".fancybox").fancybox();

}
function failureGalleryContent(data, target) {
   // console.log(data);
    $(target).text("Ocurrió un error en la carga la sección parallax. Por favor revise la consola para más información");
}


function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

function setCategories(boolLang, objResult){
var cat ="";
    for(var item in objResult){
     if(boolLang)
        cat += replaceAll(" ", "_",objResult[item].English.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '')) + ' ';
     else
        cat += replaceAll(" ", "_",objResult[item].Title.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '')) + ' ';
    }
    return cat;
}

function replaceAll( find, replace,string) {
  return string.replace(new RegExp(escapeRegExp(find), 'g'), replace);
}
function escapeRegExp(string) {
    return string.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
}
```

The problem is that I don´t know why first take one image of each category and after that get all images of one categorie, for example
I have this categories

Services, Home, Office

In my first row of images I get:

```
firstimageServices
firstimageHome
firstimageOffice
secondimageOffice
thirdimageOffice
etc...
```

But I want to group all by categorie, so it will be:

```
firstimageServices
secondimageServices
thirdimageServices
fourimageServices
etc...
firstimageHome
secondimageHome
thirdimageHome
fourimageHome
etc...
firstimageOffice
secondimageOffice
thirdimageOffice
fourimageOffice
etc..
```

How can I do in my query to group it? Regards!

Note: I look something of interest in these link [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc751316.aspx) but how can I apply it in my query to sort by "Title"

So In first fields I get something like that:
[image]

When it pass first rows of categories I get that I want like these:
[image]

Comment: You want sort the AJAX result ? Or  want update the webservice to return ordered result? For the first, are you image really name `firstimage, secondimage` or there is some id or date to sort for? for second we need the code for webservice

Comment: I want to order,  firstimage, secondimage of the same category have the same Title, so I want to order it by title @JuanCarlosOropeza

Comment: You didnt understand my comment. We need more information to do that.

Comment: My image have different names, and they don´t have id or date to sort, I Wi´ll post all my code @JuanCarlosOropeza

Comment: I upload some pictures  @JuanCarlosOropeza

Comment: Still dont understand what you want sorry :(.

Comment: I solved it, just modified my query for orderby function:

Answer (score 0):

I finally do it just change query for:

```
"$select=Title,Description,Enlace,EncodedAbsUrl,Categoria/Title&$expand=Categor‌​i‌​a/Title&$orderby=Title asc";
```